# How to create 3D Wavelets using 1D and/or 2D Wavelets?

Tags: 3d, decomposition, wavelet-transform

I have the MATLAB code for `1D Wavelets` and `2D Wavelets`decompositions. How can I create `3D Wavelets` using 1D and 2D Wavelets?
I do not want to use MATLAB's built-in function `wavedec3`.

Answer (score 2):

Wavelet transforms can be represented as [separable filters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separable_filter).
Combining 1D and 2D wavelet transforms can be done straightforwardly by taking advantage of their separability.

Specifically:
Suppose that you have a 3D dataset "data" of NX x NY x NZ voxels.
A possible 3D wavelet transform in pseudocode would be:

```
for iz = 0 .. NZ - 1:
   FWT2D(data[:, :, iz]) //apply 2D transform to the slices

tmp = 0 * [NZ][NY][NX] //initialize 

//x-z transposition to have unit-stride in z
for ix = 0 .. NX - 1:
   for iz = 0 .. NZ - 1:
       tmp[iz, :, ix] = data[ix, :, iz]

for ix = 0 .. NX - 1:
   for iy = 0 .. NY - 1:
       FWT1D(tmp[:, iy, ix]) //apply 1D transform to z-streams

//transpose back
for ix = 0 .. NX - 1:
   for iz = 0 .. NZ - 1:
       data[ix, :, iz] = tmp[iz, :, ix]
```

The proposed solution is written "around" your 1D and 2D wavelet transforms, 
i.e. it should allow for a direct reuse of your kernels with no code modifications.
Remark: I assumed that your kernels implement *full wavelet transforms*, not just the one-step transform.

If you do not like the transpositions, fair enough :-),  you should modify your 1D transform to allow a non unit-stride access of the data to jump along the z-direction.

Analogous algorithms can be derived if you need to apply 2D kernel to operate in XZ or YZ directions.

One last remark: since wavelet transforms translate to separable filters, you could in theory combine different wavelets along the different directions.